# Speed Up Processing of SQL in Access 2007

Tags: sql, performance

I've been trying to get this SQL query I am using in an Access 2007 database to execute faster.  I've already eliminated any distinct queries involved -- and Access doesn't really give me too much information on where the hang-up is.  The query is pulling about 150,000 rows and is taking about 2 minutes to complete.

I'm still learning the syntax for sql in access, but I think I have it setup correctly.  I'd appreciate any insights or hints on what I might be missing.

```
SELECT OLS_UNITS_GROSS_ACRES.AGMT_NUM, 
MAX(OLS_UNITS_GROSS_ACRES.UNIT_GROSS_ACRES) AS UNIT_GROSS, 
SUM(MIS_ACREAGES.ACRE_AMT) AS [RELATED ACRES]
FROM ((OLS_UNITS_GROSS_ACRES 
INNER JOIN MIS_XREFERENCED_AGMTS_M ON OLS_UNITS_GROSS_ACRES.ARRG_KEY = MIS_XREFERENCED_AGMTS_M.ACTIVE_ARRG_KEY) 
INNER JOIN ALL_AGMTS1 ON = MIS_XREFERENCED_AGMTS_M.RELATED_ARRG_KEY = ALL_AGMTS1.ARRG_KEY) 
INNER JOIN MIS_ACREAGES ON ALL_AGMTS1.ARRG_KEY = MIS_ACREAGES.ARRG_KEY
WHERE (((ALL_AGMTS1.SUBJ_CODE)="LSE") 
AND (((MIS_ACREAGES.ACRE_TYPE_CODE)="CNT") 
OR ((MIS_ACREAGES.ACRE_TYPE_CODE)="STN") 
OR ((MIS_ACREAGES.ACRE_TYPE_CODE)="DNT")))
GROUP BY OLS_UNITS_GROSS_ACRES.AGMT_NUM;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could try. Eliminating any DISTINCT Queries is a good start. Another way to speed it up would be to create an index for fields that are frequently queried and or sorted. This will speed up the SELECT query, however it does slow down any INSERT commands as it now has to insert information into the index as well as the table.

If your database design is stable and its objects will not be renamed, you can safely turn off Name AutoCorrect to improve performance.

Over time, the performance of a database file can become slow because of space that remains allocated to deleted or temporary objects. The Compact and Repair command removes this wasted space and can help a database run faster and more efficiently.

I got most of this from the following link. It had several other ideas, but those were the best ones; http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/help-access-run-faster-HA010235589.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this particular dataset is coming from an Oracle 10 database and I don't have access to add any more indexes on that side.  I won't be doing any inserts, as this is a read-only operation.  I am also repairing/compacting on file close.